# Linking.removeEventListener required params

Tags: react-native

If I declared in a useEffect hook

```
Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => {
  handleUrl({ url, userDetails });
});
```

In the cleanup function of the hook is it enough to write `Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleUrl);` or do I have to pass the same params as in the declared `Linking.addEventListener`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always declare the handler first, do not use inline function

```
const myhandler =({url}) => {
  handleUrl({ url, userDetails });
});
```

Then attach it to listener

```
Linking.addEventListener('url', myhandler);
```

And remove it like

```
Linking.removeEventListener('url', myhandler);
```

Answer (score 7):

Answer for React Native in 2022, you should remove an event like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const urlListener = Linking.addEventListener('url', handleUrl);

    return () => {
      urlListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: What about the class component?

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) for `removeEventListener()`  only the type and handler are necessary: `removeEventListener(type, handler);`